# Deleting Search Nav node in powershell CSOM

Tags: search, powershell, client-object-model

I have created a script that adds my search nav to my search site but it is still left with what was already there as out of the box. I am having trouble with finding how I can delete the nodes I don't want.
Here is my code at the moment :

```
$Navigation = $ctx.Web.Navigation
$searchNavigation = $Nav.GetNodeById(1040);
$nodeC=$searchNavigation.Children
$ctx.Load($nodeC)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach ($Node in $nodeC)
{
    $Node.DeleteObject()


}
```

this doesn't delete the nodes, just give the error

> Error while creating search result page. Error -->> The collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using foreach loop, try performing operation using a for loop.

```
for($node=0;$node -lt $nodeC.Count;$node++){
$nodeVal = $nodeC[$node];
$nodeC.Delete($nodeVal);}
```

Comment: For completeness, can you please add a code example that uses a for-loop in above scenario

Comment: Added Code example